# opendaylight 0.9.2 installation and configuration

Tags: opendaylight

I downloaded opendaylight 0.9.2, installed in rhel 7.2. as per doc, I run ./karaf, then I try to install the karaf features, but it cannot install the features like "alto", dlux etc.
I'm trying to configure the RHEL system as SDN controller for connecting to CISCO 3172TQ switch.

Have anyone tried installing the same? how to overcome the above issue?

Answer (score 1):

Some Oxygen projects are not available in Fluorine release, please see full list in: https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-fluorine/